# Set value of input field, based on click on a set of a href links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML Code, with few  links, as :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#brad_button_770103363').click(function() {
    //alert($(this).text());
    var paypal = $(this).text();
    //$('#paypal_donate_amount').val(paypal).trigger('change');
    $('#paypal_donate_amount').val(paypal);
    var paypal = null;
    console.log(paypal);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="" id="brad_button_770103363">$20</a>
<a href="" id="brad_button_770103363">$50</a>
<!-- similar 10 links... -->

<input type="text" id="paypal_donate_amount" />
```

Now, I want that for each new click, on ahref, its val() i.e 20, 50 Nmerical value only, is updated in this input field & overwrites old value of input.

But, it simply updates value of 1st click only. On subsequent, click nothing happens in input field values. Where i am wrong ? Also, how to remove $ sign ? Plz help.

Comment: I'd expect that an `href` of `""` would throw a `404`.

Comment: You have two links with the same ID, and that will lead to bugs.

Comment: When you say "1st click only", do you mean *only the first link works*, or *it only works the first time you click it*?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.brad_button_770103363').click(function(){
        var paypal = $(this).text();
        $('#paypal_donate_amount').val(paypal);
        var paypal = null;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="brad_button_770103363">$20</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="brad_button_770103363">$50</a>

<input type="text" id="paypal_donate_amount" />
```

What I have done is adding `href="javascript:void(0)"` so it doesn't behave like a link. And the IDs became classes, so if they are repeated, it's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks !! DONE. href="javascript:void(0)" - Awesome Trick

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the HTML content, I would suggest something like this...

```js
$(function() {
  $('.donateAmount').click(function() {
    $('#paypal_donate_amount').val($(this).data('amount'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="donateAmount" data-amount=20>$20</a>
<a href="#" class="donateAmount" data-amount=50>$50</a>
<input type="text" id="paypal_donate_amount" value="0" />
```

Comment: StackOverflow supports inline snippets :)

Comment: Thansk TONS. href="javascript:void(0)" - worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

change the id to class as id is unique, unlike class

```
<a href="" class="brad_button_770103363">$20</a>
<a href="" class="brad_button_770103363">$50</a>

<input type="text" id="paypal_donate_amount" />

<script type="text/javascript">

$.noConflict();


$(function(){
    $('.brad_button_770103363').click(function(){
        //alert($(this).text());
        var paypal = $(this).text();
        //$('#paypal_donate_amount').val(paypal).trigger('change');
        $('#paypal_donate_amount').val(paypal);
        var paypal = null;
        console.log(paypal);

    });
});
```

try the code and get back, did not test it for errors

Comment: *"did not test it for errors"* - I'd suggest you do :)

Comment: Tested it. Working but, my .php page refreshes on each click on this link n input field value gets RESET to null. Why ? Also, i dont want $ sign in input field. Plz help

Comment: you have this line var paypal=null, what does it actually do?

Comment: @user3670334 Read the first comment on your question :)

Comment: if you want to prevent the page from refreshing you have to use javascript preventdefault. e.g $('.brad_button..').click(function(event){event.preventDefault()})

Comment: @EmekaOkafor - not sure what the `???` is for. I was talking to the user I tagged. In any case: rather than going out of your way to disable the default behavior of a link, just *remove* the `href` attribute altogether. If you still want the "hand" cursor, then use CSS.

Comment: @tyler Roper what impact does it have on the load time?

Comment: @user3670334 if found useful remember to tag your useful answer so as to close this thread